# htaccess - redirect directory to file with same name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I seem to be having an issue I have found no solution to.

I have a directory and a file with the same name set up and I cannot seem to find a way to redirect the directory to the file in the root folder. All the info I found was for rewriting or redirect to a file in the subdirectory.

> dir: example.com/en-gb/
>
> file: example.com/en-gb (extension removed with htaccess)

Current htaccess (relevant part):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /en-gb [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en-gb/$
RewriteRule . ../en-gb [R,L]
```

This just results in the following error:

> You don't have permission to access /en-gb/.html on this server.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Comment: "extension removed with htaccess" - so the file does have an extension? Presumably `en-gb.html`? The directives that rewrite to the actual file and the order of these directives are going to be important - these should be added to your question.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not actually removing the extension with `.htaccess` -  are you? `.htaccess` is used to add the extension back (converting the URL back into a filesystem path), not remove it.

Comment: yeah I expressed myself in a wrong way. I used it to remove the extension from the url but of course it still exists behind the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily, when you request `/directory`, mod_dir issues a 301 redirect to append a trailing slash, ie. `/directory/` (to "fix" the URL). mod_dir is then able to serve the directory index document from within that directory.

Unfortunately, this would appear to occur *before* mod_rewrite is able to process the request. So, you are going to have to disable this behaviour in `.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

You can then internally rewrite the request to the file instead. eg. `/directory` gets internally rewritten to `/directory.html` if it exists:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

However, disabling `DirectorySlash` has it's caveats - you are going to have to make sure that any requests for directories already have trailing slashes (or check for this in `.htaccess` as well). And note the security warning in the docs.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash